# what is the length of this variable (IF statement)

Tags: sas

The following is the code:

```
data test;
   set sasdata.chemist(keep=job_code);
   if job_code = 'chem3'
   then description = 'Senior Chemist';
run;
```

The variable job_code is a character variable with a length of 6 bytes. Then, what is the length of the variable description in the output data set? For my understanding, the description variable is still missing, since the if statement is evaluated false. So, the length is 0. But the right answer is 14 bytes. Why 14? Could anyone explain to me? Many thanks for your time and attention.

**EDIT:**
Since the following code is also related to the length of a variable, it makes sense to put it together.

```
data work.test;
  Author = 'Agatha Christie';
  First = substr(scan(author, 1, ','),1,1);
run;
```

So the length to the variable 'First' is 200 according to the answer sheet. I understand that the variable length is determined at the compilation time. Still, why is it 200? Any comments would be greatly appreciated.

PS. With java, python, r, and matlab experiences, I find SAS to be a bit strange compared with the others. I really appreciate all your comments, whatever it is. Of course, I especially appreciate all the encouragements, which literally brighten my day. I will read more, and try not to ask trivial questions.

Comment: Have to say I don't understand why Lucy's questions keep getting downvotes.  They're very clearly stated and well explained.  Yes, Lucy doesn't understand SAS very well, but that's rather why we're here answering questions, isn't it?

Comment: Because we are not studying for the Base SAS Certification, Lucy is (my guess).  These are all questions that are explained in the study guide.  Lucy is relying on StackOverflow to do her homework instead of doing her reading, and analytically thinking through the problem.

Comment: @DomPazz This particular question shows research (Lucy has presented what she thinks it should be and why), is clearly stated, and may help others - therefor none of the downvote reasons should apply IMO.

Comment: Indeed, @RobertPenridge.  Dom, while I might get tired of answering them eventually, I don't think any of these questions are particularly lacking of research: They show a lack of *understanding*, which is what we're here for.  The SAS data step is quite confusing, particularly for those of other programming backgrounds who expect it to work like those other programming environments; I don't particularly expect people to understand the intricacies of the PDV, even after reading papers on the topic.

Comment: Max on SAS-L is a good example of someone like Lucy originally: had a lot of basic questions about the PDV and such, just like this.  Eventually got that understanding through others answering his questions - and now is a useful contributor to the list in his own right.

Comment: To be fair, I did not down-vote this question as I agree it is well stated showing some thought went into it.  Some of the others have not been.

Comment: I think they're valid and thoughtful questions, but I feel that they've been already been thoroughly answered on here or elsewhere before. There are many resources for Base SAS certification questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps a bit more detail than Tom's answer is appropriate here.

When the SAS process receives code for a data step, it goes through what can be thought of as three distinct stages.

- Macro parsing
- Compilation
- Execution

Macro parsing isn't necessary in all instances, but it still checks first to see if there are any macro tokens (things with `%` or `&`) to parse.

Then, it goes through the *compilation* stage.  This is where SAS works out what the data step is going to be doing.  Before any data is processed, SAS knows:

- What the input dataset(s) are
- What the output dataset(s) are
- What variables are on the input dataset(s)
- What variables need to be defined in the [PDV](http://analytics.ncsu.edu/sesug/2005/IN09_05.PDF) - where data is stored *during* processing
- What variables will be output to the output dataset(s)
- What length the variables are
- What format the variables have, and will have
- The order of the variables

... and a lot of other information.  All of this is determined before any data is read.  The information that comes from the input dataset(s) is available in the first several blocks of the dataset (basically, anything that PROC CONTENTS is capable of producing is stored there).  That's all read, and then worked out, before any data is read.

Then the data is read, and things like `if` statements are executed, in the execution stage.

This is why you can't change the lengths of variables, or which ones are kept or dropped, or the format of the variables, in IF blocks.  Nothing that the compilation stage does depends on the data: all of it is known *beforehand*.

Instead, what SAS does when it sees a new variable in the data step, is it immediately creates a new entry in the PDV for it.  It looks at the code and decides how long to make it, gives it a default format, label, etc.  Once it's been created (after that first encounter), it won't change any of these things even if it sees it again later on.

So, for example, in this code:

```
data test;
  x="Hello";
  output;
  x="Goodbye";
  output;
run;
```

What do you think is in `test`?

The following:

```
_N_=1 x=Hello
_N_=2 x=Goodb
```

Yep.  You lost a few characters because SAS made it 5 long based on the first instance of x.  You could of course define the length yourself, or switch the order of these statements, and get a different result.

And then, if you write:

```
data test;
  if 0 then x='Hello';
  if 1 then x='Goodbye';
  output;
run;
```

What will you get now?

The answer:

```
_N_=1 x=GOODB
```

The SAS compiler saw the first line, and even though it's obvious that `if 0` is false, it doesn't care: it's still going to do the same thing as it always does.  It sees `x='Hello'`, makes an x variable on the PDV.  Then the execution stage occurs, and it actually processes the `if` statements; thus only the second line is created/output.  But it's still only 5 long!

I recommend reading some of the core SAS documentation here, particularly the [Introduction to DATA Step processing](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/basess/68381/HTML/default/n13roklnfoocgin1dom3okvctnvi.htm).  There are also quite a few good papers (and books) on the subject; search terms in addition to "SAS Data step" are "PDV" (program data vector) and "Compilation" vs "Execution".

Comment: Great explanation Joe.  Bookmarking this question just so I can refer people to this answer.

Comment: Yes, very nice.  The distinction between compile-time activities and execution-time activities is critical to anyone learning SAS.  I still remember my first SAS course.  Not having a programming background, I kept thinking "why does this instructor keep talking about compile time and execution time? I just want to clean data an analyze it."  I'm grateful to him (and many others).  Also +1 on impressive rapid evolution of Max on SAS-L from newbie with intro questions to experienced contributor.

Answer (score 2):

SAS will define the type and length of a variable as soon as it can.  It will set the length based its best guess of what you meant by the code it sees.  It does this during the compilation of the data step before the step starts executing.

In your case the first reference to `description` is in the assignment statement. Since it is being assigned a string that is 14 bytes long it defines the variable as character of length 14.

The first reference to `job_code` is in the `SET` statement.  SAS will create `job_code` to match how it was defined in the source dataset.  That is why it is defined as length 6 instead of being defined as length 5 to match the length of `'chem3'`.

If the first reference to a variable is the assignment of the result of a character function then SAS will normally default to length $200.

If you want to be certain of how your variables are defined then use `LENGTH` or `ATTRIB` statement to explicitly define them before using them in other statements.

You also seem to be confusing the length of a particular value of the variable and the defined maximum length of the variable.  SAS stores character variables as fixed length.  When you talk about the length of a variable it is this defined maximum length that is normally meant. When you assign a shorter value to the variable then it is padded with blanks to fill the space.

You can use the `LENGTH()` function to calculate the length of a value stored in a character variable (or a string literal).  The length is the location of the last non-blank character in the string.  Also note that by convention an all blank string will have a length of 1.  You can use the `LENGTHN()` function if you prefer to consider an all blank string as having length of 0.

Answer (score 0):

Because the length of the variable would get assigned at compile time, not at run time. When the code compiles, it will compile all the steps, not just the steps when if condition is true.

So in this case, the length is being assigned as the length required to store the text 'Senior Chemist', which is 14